# Is there an equivalent of partialmethod for properties?

Tags: python, properties, python-descriptors

I have a class with many parameters that are stored in a dictionary as below (in practice, it's a bit more complex, but this gives a good idea). I am able to 'autogenerate' get and set methods using `partialmethod`:

```
for a_name in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
  locals()["get_" + a_name] = partialmethod(_get_arg, 
                                            arg_name=a_name) 
  locals()["set_" + a_name] = partialmethod(_set_arg, 
                                            arg_name=a_name)
```

Ideally, I wanted to use `@property`, but only if I can 'autogenerate' `@property`, `@setter` and `@deleter`. Would it be possible? The second snippet show the 'manually' added properties; I am looking into using an equivalent of `partialmethod` to avoid repetition and unmaintainable code.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kwargs = {'x' : 0, 'y' : 3, 'z' : True}

    def __get_arg(self, arg_name):
        assert arg_name in self.kwargs
        return self.kwargs[arg_name]

    def __set_arg(self, arg_name, value):
        assert arg_name in self.kwargs
        self.kwargs[arg_name] = value

    def __del_arg(self, arg_name):
        assert arg_name in self.kwargs
        del self.kwargs[arg_name]

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__get_arg('x')

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self.__set_arg('x', value)

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        self.__del_arg('x')

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__get_arg('y')

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self.__set_arg('y', value)

    @y.deleter
    def y(self):
        self.__del_arg('y')

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.__get_arg('z')

    @x.setter
    def z(self, value):
        self.__set_arg('z', value)

    @x.deleter
    def z(self):
        self.__del_arg('z')


c = C()
c.x = 'foo'  # setter called
foo = c.x    # getter called
del c.x      # deleter called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own descriptor type, and use the `__set_name__` method that will get called on it (by the class creation machinery) to figure out what name it's been saved to in the class:

```
class MyProp:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
             return self
        return instance._get_arg(self.name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance._set_arg(self.name, value)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        instance._del_arg(self.name)
```

You'd use it this way:

```
 class C:
     # define __init__, _get_arg, etc.

     x = MyProp()
     y = MyProp()
     z = MyProp()
```

Note that because it's code from another class calling the `_X_arg` methods, you probably don't want to do name mangling, so I've changed the `__` prefixes to just a single `_`.

Comment: Thanks! would MyProp be C's internal class? In `x = MyProp()`, would it be more like `self.my_properties['x'] = C.MyProp(self, 'x')` etc.?

Comment: But I still have to create x = MyProp(), y = MyProp(), z = MyProp() one by one, there is no way I can create them in a loop and still use the getters and setters as I want to, right?

Comment: I suppose you could define `MyProp` inside of `C`, but there's no need to do so. And you could use a loop to set them I suppose, but I think it would be a lot uglier and harder to understand than what I showed. You might consider using a class decorator to add the descriptors, though you'd need to set the name yourself, since `__set_name__` only gets called at class creation time. A metaclass could also work (and would call `__set_name__` automatically), but then it's less obvious how you specify the list of property names you want.

Comment: @Bickknight Could I ask what's the advantage of `__ set_name__`  over `__init__` with the same contents? Not having to pass `name` as a parameter? Sorry for the delayed response, had to do something else urgently.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it's automatic is the main advantage of using `__set_name__`. If you wrote an `__init__` method that takes `name` as its argument, you'd need to write `x = MyProp('x')` which is a bit redundant. It might work better with alternative approaches to creating the attributes, but in my answer I wanted to highlight the descriptor approach.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for awhile, I came up with the following `partialproperty` descriptor.

The `__get__` method is called when an attribute is accessed. In it I call the
`setter()` method with the first argument of `obj` for the `self` paramater
followed by the unpacked `self.args` and `self.kwargs`.

```py
class partialproperty:
    """Combine the functionality of property() and partialmethod()"""
    def __init__(self, getter, setter=None, deleter=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.getter = getter
        self.setter = setter
        self.deleter = deleter
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._name = name
        self._owner = owner

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.getter(obj, *self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.setter is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"{self._owner.__class__.__name__} object can't set attribute: {self._name}")

        self.setter(obj, *self.args, value, **self.kwargs)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.deleter is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"{self._owner.__class__.__name__} object can't delete attribute: {self._name}")

        self.deleter(obj, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

You can use it in a class to create property attributes like so, much like you
would with `partialmethod()`.

If you don't need a setter and deleter, you need to either use keyword
arguments for your args, or explicitly pass `None`.

```py
class RGBA:
    def __init__(self, rgba):
        self.rgba = rgba

    def _component_(self, idx):
        return self.rgba[idx]

    # using keyword args
    red = partialproperty(_component_, idx=0)
    green = partialproperty(_component_, idx=1)
    blue = partialproperty(_component_, idx=2)

    # this has the same effect but with positional args
    alpha = partialproperty(_component_, None, None, 3)
```

Then in your instances the respective attributes will behave like properties.

```py
>>> color = RGBA([0, 75, 255, 1])
>>> color.red
0
>>> color.green
75
>>> color.blue
255
>>> color.alpha
1
```

For your example it would look like:

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __get_arg(self, arg_name):
        try:
            return self.kwargs[arg_name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(arg_name)

    def __set_arg(self, arg_name, value):
        self.kwargs[arg_name] = value

    def __del_arg(self, arg_name):
        try:
            del self.kwargs[arg_name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(arg_name)

    x = partialproperty(__get_arg, __set_arg, __del_arg, "x")
    y = partialproperty(__get_arg, __set_arg, __del_arg, "y")
    z = partialproperty(__get_arg, __set_arg, __del_arg, "z")
```

```py
>>> obj = C(x=24)
>>> obj.x
24

>>> obj.y = 25
>>> obj.y
25

>>> del obj.y
>>> obj.y
AttributeError: y

>>> obj.kwargs["z"] = 26
>>> obj.z
26
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, an easier way to do this would probably to subclass
`dict` then define the magic methods `__getattr__`, `__setattr__`, and
`__delattr__` which are each called when an attribute doesn't exist. Then you
can call `super()` to inherit the behavior from the `dict` class.

```py
class AttrDict(dict):
    attrs = ("x", "y", "z")
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not name in self.attrs:
            raise AttributeError(name)

        try:
            return super().__getitem__(name)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if not name in self.attrs:
            raise AttributeError(name)

        try:
            return super().__setitem__(name, value)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if not name in self.attrs:
            raise AttributeError(name)

        try:
            return super().__delitem__(name)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)
```

```py
>>> obj = AttrDict(x=24)
>>> obj.x
24

>>> obj.a = 1
AttributeError: a

>>> obj.y = 25
>>> obj.y
25

>>> del obj.y
>>> obj.y
AttributeError: y

>>> obj.kwargs["z"] = 26
>>> obj.z
26
```

If you don't care about restricting to specific attributes it's even easier.
You can simply assign each `__*attr__` method to its cooresponding
`dict.__*item__` method, which is what gets called for subscription operations.
(ie `obj[key]`)

```py
class AttrDict(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

```py
>>> obj = AttrDict({"a": 1})
>>> obj.a
1

>>> obj["b"] = 2
>>> obj.b
2

>>> del obj.b
>>> obj.b
KeyError
```